# Scrapy DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS doesn't work

Tags: python, scrapy

I change the default request headers in `settings.py` as below:

```
DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4',
}
```

However, it doesn't work in my HotSpider. I can see `scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware` was enabled, but connection was closed cleanly as if the headers were not set.

Here is the HotSpider:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import scrapy
    
    class HotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "hot"
        allowed_domains = ["qiushibaike.com"]
        start_urls = (
            'http://www.qiushibaike.com/hot',
        )
        
        def parse(self, response):
            print '\n', response.status, '\n'
```

If I change the code to override the `make_requests_from_url` to set the header, everything works well.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import scrapy


    class HotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "hot"
        allowed_domains = ["qiushibaike.com"]
        start_urls = (
            'http://www.qiushibaike.com/hot',
        )
        headers =  {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4',
        }
    
        def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
            return scrapy.http.Request(url, headers=self.headers)
    
    
        def parse(self, response):
            print '\n', response.status, '\n'
```

---

This problem will be settled in Scrapy 1.2 according to [prioritize default headers over user agent middlewares #2091](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/2091)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see User-Agent header is indeed not set properly when using default headers middleware and this particular site refuses connections without some expected user-agent header.

Recommended way to set user-agent for your crawler is by using USER_AGENT setting key:

e.g.

```
# settings.py
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36"
```

not setting user-agent when using default headers might be some bug in Scrapy, or maybe this is expected and documented somewhere. You need to do more research about this, if it is indeed bug it's worth posting bug report in Scrapy github repo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The way you recommended to set user-agent works well.

In documents, I find [User-Agen](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#user-agent) and [DefaultHeadersMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware).According to the doc, I think this is a bug.